# How to Update and Delete MySQL JSON type field or arraylist using Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm working on user roles and permissions, in my database every role have list of permissions. The permissions field is JSON type it's cast into array in Role model.

But my problem is I can't insert, update, delete operation using Laravel Eloquent.

Here is my code sample.

```
<tr>
    <td></td> 
    @foreach($role->permissions as $key=>$value)
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="permisssions[{{$key}}]" value="{{$value}}" {{ $value==1 ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
```

When I use `$request->all()` it shows all data.

```
{
"_method": "PUT",
"_token": "gPtYT0Qj7LtG5MNTMvtn5qZGofIxfkAyhpyhV5qP",
"role": "User",
"permisssions": {
"read": "1",
"create": "1"
}
}
```

But when I use `$request->permissions`, it shows nothing.

Here is my controller.

```
public function role_permissions_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return $request->permissions;
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `$request->all()` shows that you misspelled "permissions" as "permisssions" (three S's).

You will need to either use `$request->permisssions` or update the code that creates the request.